# VueJS 2 Router is not working when it is in production build

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Hi people I have a working VueJS project in the development however the router stops to work in the production build.

I have checked online and found this solution
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/issues/11
however it doesnt give me any practical information.

routest.js

```
import News from './components/frontend/News.vue'
import News1 from './components/frontend/News1.vue'
export const routes = [
{path: '/news', component: News1},
{path: '/', component: News}
];
```

My main.js'

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import {routes} from "./routest";
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
});
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

My App.vue

```
 <template>
 <div id="app">
     <router-view></router-view>
 </div>
 </template>
 <script>
 export default {
 name: 'app',
 data () {
     return {
          msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
```

I assume something is wrong here

```
 export const routes = [
 {path: '/news', component: News1},
 {path: '/', component: News}
 ];
```

I put on my server and entered with IP
The main page appears but the news doesnt when I enter the link.
http://xxx/news

Can someone assist please?

**UPDATE 1:**
https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-vue-router  if I add

```
<router-link to="/news">About</router-link>
<router-view></router-view>
```

At App.Vue I can click from the home page and go to the news. BUT I want the freedom to go there by the direct link. How can I do that?

**Update 2**
I added this to the nginx inside the http section of the nginx.conf

```
server {
   # hostname or ip or multiple separated by spaces
   server_name localhost example.com 192.168.1.1; #change to your setting
  location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  }
```

still when I request the link directly from the server it doesnt go.
Still when I wanted the exact link from the server it didnt show anything

[image: Where I should put this location stuff. Currently it is in etc/nginx]

**ANSWER:**
So the place where I put was nginx.conf I have put that server { tag inside the http {

I checked and found include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*; 
I looked inside and there was default.cnf  in that part I saw there was already server { tag and there there was location section.

I just changed that section according to the VUEJS requirement and then it worked. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Have you added a .htaccess configuration from: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html ?

Comment: Yes I am currently looking into that. I am setting up the server. Will let you know.

Comment: @DawidLoranc I am using nginx do u know where I will put

location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

Comment: Is it nginx.conf ?

Comment: I have a separate directory for server configurations. In nginx.conf I have (in http section): include c:/nginx/conf/servers/*.conf;

Comment: @DawidLoranc Editted my question... I put that location stuff inside the nginx.conf

Comment: Is it Windows server or Linux?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put that in your nginx.conf:

```
http {
   ## ...
   ## other configuration

   server {
        listen 80;

        server_name yourservername.com;
        root html/path_to_your_project;

        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

It's working configuration for me. Make sure you flushed DNS cache and restarted Nginx.