# How to manage nginx docker image?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, nginx-config, docker-command

I'm having another separate issue, but I found a solution for it in the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959917/vuejs-2-router-is-not-working-when-it-is-in-production-build). As suggested there, I will need to modify my `nginx server` by adding the section

```
http {
   ## ...
   ## other configuration

   server {
        listen 80;

        server_name yourservername.com;
        root html/path_to_your_project;

        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

at the file: `etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.cnf`, where it seems that there is already the tag `server {` and I just need to add the section from above inside of it.

But, since I'm working with docker image and not the real server itself, I'm not sure how to accomplish this. This is my `.Dockerfile` and I'm not sure what changes I will need to do inside of it.

```
# build stage
FROM node:9.11.1-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i npm@latest -g && \
    npm install
COPY . .
RUN node build/build.js

# production stage
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: i would create my own image based on alpine with nginx installed and configured and then use that as the image for the file. so basically i woudl pull an alpine image start an interactive session edit the nginx .cnf file save it and that would be it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

1. Create the nginx.conf file locally and copy it to the container at the time of container start (Using COPY command - Dockerfile)
2. Create your own image. Then use docker-compose to up containers. There you can volume nginx configuration locations of your container to somewhere in your localhost location. This will allow you to change the configurations anytime you want without login to the container.

This is a docker-compose example that I use

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  <containerAlias>:
    image: <myNginxImage>:<tag>
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./config/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./logs/nginx_logs:/var/log/nginx
    privileged: true
    networks:
      <MyNetworkName>:
        ipv4_address: <IP>
    restart: always
    container_name: <containerName>

 ....
 ....
 ....
```

3. Log into the container and install a text editor (vi, nano, etc). And open the nginx.conf file using an installed text editor and apply the changes.

Make sure to change the configurations according to your environment. **I prefer you to go with option 2**.